# Is there a geometrical interpretation to the notion of eigenvector and eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition

The wiki [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue,_eigenvector_and_eigenspace) on eigenvectors offers the following geometrical interpretation:

> Each application of the matrix to an arbitrary vector yields a result which will have rotated towards the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue.

Qn 1: If there is any other geometrical interpretation particularly in the context of a covariance matrix?

The wiki also discusses the difference between left and right eigenvectors.

Qn 2: Do the above geometrical interpretations hold irrespective of whether they are left or right eigenvectors?

Comment: The left eigenvectors of M are the right eigenvectors of M^T, so if you understand the transpose then the geometric interpretations are essentially the same.

Comment: [Principal Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) transforms the data to a basis of eigenvectors with the largest eigenvalues in order to reduce dimension while minimizing information loss.

Comment: @Qiaochu: That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Kaestur: So my understanding of your comment and based on the wiki article is this: The eigenvector associated with the highest eigenvalue is parallel to the major axis of the ellipsoid associated with the covariance matrix. Would that be correct?

Comment: @Srikant: Mostly correct. Clustering and such can make it a little complicated. I realized wikipedia does not have a good picture, perhaps [this](http://www.med.govt.nz/templates/MultipageDocumentPage____1065.aspx#P1096_144597) may help.

Comment: @Kaestur Hakarl - that link is broken :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a partial answer in the case where M is a real symmetric matrix.  This is to ensure, by the real spectral theorem, that M has real eigenvectors with real eigenvalues, so there is a chance for a genuine geometric interpretation which stays in $R^n$.

M acts on the unit sphere in $R^n$ in the following way: it sends the unit sphere $v^T v = 1$ to $v^T (M^T M) v = 1$ .  This modified shape is not generally a sphere, but is generally an ellipsoid.  The axes of this ellipsoid are the eigenvectors of M, and the sizes of each axis are given by the squares of the corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: +1 @Qiaochu: I find your method of thinking about "how M modifies the unit sphere" to be very interesting and useful. By the way, why do you say it is a partial answer?

Your comment on my second qn + the above response answers my question (at least from my perspective).

Comment: I haven't addressed the case where M is allowed to be symmetric or complex.

Comment: Fair enough but I am ok with your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of giving an answer, let me point out to you this [chapter](https://mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/moler/eigs.pdf) in Cleve Moler's book "Numerical Computing with MATLAB", there is a nice geometric demonstration in MATLAB on how eigenvalues/eigenvectors (as well as singular values/vectors) of an order-2 square matrix are involved in how a circle is transformed into an ellipse after a linear transformation represented by the matrix.

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in covariance matrices, then the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix tell you how to change variables to make your random variables uncorrelated.

Specifically, let $M$ be a covariance matrix of the random variables $X_1,...,X_n$. For simplicity, lets assume that all of these random variables are zero mean. Lets also define $X$ to be the random vector whose $i$"th component is the random variable $X_i$. Let the eigenvectors of $M$ be $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$. We can assume that these are orthogonal since $M$ is symmetric. Consider the random variables $Y_i$ obtained by taking the dot product of $v_i$ and $X$.

Then the random variables $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ are uncorrelated!

Indeed:

$$ E[ Y_i Y_j] = E[ v_i^T X X^T v_j] = v_i^T M v_j = \lambda_j v_i^T v_j = 0 $$

Comment: that's what i was looking for. good show!

Answer (score 2):

Of course! Consider a coordinate transformation of rotation and/or scaling (but not translation):

```
v = Au
```

where v and u are vectors, and A is a transformation matrix. Then the eigenvectors, if they have real components, are the axes which are left unrotated (scaling only) by the transformation. (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue,_eigenvector_and_eigenspace))

A covariance matrix is a symmetric, positive definite matrix, so it has orthonormal eigenvectors, and these form a tuple of axes; I am fairly sure the eigenvectors form a new basis of linear combinations of the input variables where the basis variables are uncorrelated, but I can't remember how to show this.

<strike>For example, if w1 = [x;y] is a pair of independent unit-variance zero-mean Gaussian random variables, consider w2 = [u;v] = [1 1; 2 1][x;y] = (x+y,2x+y), so that w1 = [-1 1;2 -1][u;v] = [v-u;2u-v]. Then cov(w2) = [2 3; 3 5]. This has eigenvectors which have sqrt(5) in them, hmmmm...</strike>

As for question 2, I'm not sure.

Comment: But, this seems trivial as it follows from the definition of the eigenvector or is there something deeper I am missing?

Comment: @Srikant, could you explain in more detail what sort of answer you are looking for?

Comment: I thought the question was clear. I am looking to see if there is any deeper insight along the lines of the one suggested by the wiki. The geometrical interpretation that repeated applications will rotate a vector towards the eigenvector with the highest eigenvalue is not at all obvious at first sight. I also want to know if there is a difference between left and right eigenvectors with respect to the geometry. Does that help clarify?

Comment: I added the section on covariance matrices. forgot how to show what I wanted to show, though.